# mongo collection insert not working meteor server

Tags: mongodb, meteor, collections

I am trying to use autobahn to subscribe to the push api of poloniex (a crypto exchange) but I'm having trouble getting collection inserts to work inside the scope of the autobahn session. Inserts work fine when collection is empty in the 
initFakeData method, but don't work within the autobahn session. my console log shows the messages however. I am not getting any error messages.
Am I missing something?

```js
import { DemoCollection } from "../../../both/collections/demo.collection";
import { Demo } from "../../../both/models/demo.model";
import * as autobahn from "autobahn";


export class Main {
  start(): void {
    this.initFakeData();
  }
  

  initFakeData(): void {

    if (DemoCollection.find({}).cursor.count() === 0) {
      const data: Demo[] = [{
        name: "Dotan",
        age: 25
      }, {
        name: "Liran",
        age: 26
      }, {
        name: "Uri",
        age: 30
      }];
      data.forEach((obj: Demo) => {
        DemoCollection.insert(obj);
      });
    }
    this.initPoloTroll();
  }

  initPoloTroll(): void {
    let wsuri = "wss://api.poloniex.com";
    let connection = new autobahn.Connection({
      url: wsuri,
      realm: "realm1"
    });

    connection.onopen = (session) => {
      console.log('connection open');
      session.subscribe('trollbox', (args, kwargs) => {
        console.log({
          name: args[2],
          age: args[1]
        });

        DemoCollection.insert({
          name: args[2].toString(),
          age: args[1]
        });
      });
    }

    connection.onclose = function () {
      console.log("Websocket connection closed");
    }

    connection.open();
  }
}
```

Comment: add callback after selector in your query like function(err,result){console.log(err)}

Comment: I have tried, but any collection method fails silently. I also tried logging DemoCollection.find({}).cursor.count() from within the session, but it's not logging anything.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.eventedmind.com/items/meteor-what-is-meteor-bindenvironment

```js
connection.onopen = Meteor.bindEnvironment((session) => {
      console.log('connection open');
      session.subscribe('trollbox', Meteor.bindEnvironment((args, kwargs) => {
        let newObject = {
          name: args[2],
          age: args[1]
        };
        console.log(newObject);
        DemoCollection.insert(newObject);
        console.log('insert done');
      }));
    });
```

Comment: glad i could help